# Magento 2 When Install Extension From Web Setup Wizard Then Always Check Component Dependency Failed

Tags: magento2, admin, web-setup-wizard

I am try to install extension from web setup wizard then always or any extension try to install but give error "Error! You need to resolve these issues to continue." and Check Component Dependency fails.

Please give me help 
here is screenshot 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in [Magento Devedocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/component-depend.html).

It will resolve your issue.

Thanks